# Automatically exchange explicit type with var-keyword

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, types

I want to automatically remove all explicit types and exchange them with the var keyword in a big solution, e.g. instead of

```
int a = 1;
```

I want to have:

```
var a = 1;
```

This is just cosmetics, the code in the solution works perfectly fine, I just want to have things consistent, as I started out using explicit types, but later on used var-keywords.

I'm guessing I would have to write some sort of code parser - sounds a little cumbersome. Does anybody know an easy solution to this?

Cheers,
Chris

Comment: Personlly I only use var when the type is something long like `Dictionary<string,List<KeyValuePair<string, int>>>`.  I'd never use it instead of int as they are the same length.  But that's just my 2 cents.

Comment: Watch out for for instance: `float a = 3;` converted to `var a = 3;` would make it an int.

Comment: I'd leave it as is.  var is great for long class names and stuff you're using locally, but when it's a choice between int and var, var simply isn't as clear and readable (it's readable, just not *as* readable).

Comment: upvoted for the answers showing why not to do this

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This isn't an answer *per se*, but it's too long for a comment.

You should strongly consider **not** doing this. There's no stylistic concern with mixing explicit and inferential typing (you should infer types when you need to, either when using anonymous types or when it makes the code easier to read), and there are plenty of potential issues you'll encounter with this:

- Declarations without assignment are ineligible
- Declarations that are assigned to `null` are ineligible
- Declarations that are of a supertype but initialized to an instance of a subtype (or compatible but different type) would change their meaning.

I.E.

```
object foo = "test";

...

foo = 2;
```

Obviously, this is a simple (and unlikely) example, but changing `foo` from `object` to `var` would result in `foo` being typed as a `string` instead of `object`, and would change the semantics of the code (it wouldn't even compile in this case, but you could easily run into more difficult to find scenarios where it changes overload resolution but *doesn't* produce a compile-time error).

In other words, don't do this, please.

Comment: Thanks, this sounds perfectly reasonable to me. I'll take your advise.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, this is probably not such a good idea. There is no advantage to `var` over `int`; many declarations will be almost as simple.

But if you must...

A partly manual solution is to turn ReSharper's "Use var" hint into a warning and get it to fix them all up. I don't know if ReSharper will do it *en masse*, but I often rifle through a badly-done piece of third-party code with a rapid sequence of <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>PgDn</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

This has the significant advantage that ReSharper respects the semantics of your code. It won't replace types indiscriminately, and I'm pretty sure it will only make changes that don't affect the meaning of your program. E.g.: It won't replace `object o = "hello";` (I think; I'm not in front of VS to check this).

Answer (score 0):

Look into Lex & Yacc.  You could combine that with a perl or awk script to mechanically edit your source.

You could also do this in emacs, using CEDET.  It parses code modules and produces a table of its code analysis.

In either case you will need to come up with an analysis of the code that describes... class declarations (class name, parent types, start and end points), method declarations (similar), variable declarations, and so on.  Then you will write some code (perl, awk, powershell, elisp, whatever) that walks the table, and does the replace on each appropriate variable declaration.

Comment: Or you could just borrow gmcs and/or the gmcs grammar from the Mono project and tweak the compiler to produce source, replacing local variable declaration types with `var` when (1) it is syntactically legal, and (2) when it can be proven that using `var` does not change the type of the variable.

Comment: yes, that's the idea. There are several options I guess, for the lexer/analyzer piece.

Answer (score 0):

I'd be wary of doing this in an automated fashion.  There are places where this may actually change the semantics of the program or introduce errors.  For example,

```
 IEnumerable<string> list = MethodThatReturnsListType();
```

or

```
 string foo = null;
 if (!dict.TryGetValue( "bar", out foo ))
 {
      foo = "default";
 }
```

Since these aren't errors, I would simply replace them as you touch the code for other reasons.  That way you can inspect the surrounding code and make sure you aren't changing the semantics and avoid introducing errors that need to be fixed.

Answer (score -2):

What's about search/replace in Visual Studio IDE
For example search vor 'int ' and replace it with 'var '.

Comment: -1 for the same reasons as I commented on StingyJack's answer.

Comment: @cdhowie - no one is saying to do a global replace. Perhaps you should stop assuming and declaring these "not helpful", when they are legitimate solutions.

Comment: @StingyJack: Perhaps you need to reread the original question again anyway, as this basically calls for a C# parser.  Find/replace on an entire solution using probably over 100 different types is simply not feasible.  Unless you want to make mturk do it for you...